# Child dataclass with constant?

Tags: python, enums, typing, python-dataclasses

```
class MessageType(Enum):
    HELLO = 10

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Message:
    op: MessageType

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Hello(Message):
    op: MessageType.HELLO = field(init=False)
    foo: str
```

`Hello` is a type of `Message` with op code 10. I'd like to turn all incoming messages into sub-classed messages so that functions are type aware: `def process_hello(msg: Hello): m.foo + 123` will fail type checking, but not if we use the generic `Message` type.

```
op: MessageType.HELLO = field(init=False, default=MessageType.HELLO)
```

This seems to work but at the expense of redundantly specifying `MessageType.HELLO`, and it implies that custom op values are allowed. Is there a more Python way to do this?

Comment: `MessageType.HELLO` isn't a type; it's a *value* of type `MessageType`.

Comment: Pylance is fine with it, the type is shown as `Literal[MessageType.HELLO]`, which seems correct?

Comment: That might be behavior specific to Pylance; I don't know if other type checkers would do the same.

Comment: At the very least, you can be specific and use `Literal` yourself instead of assuming it will be inferred.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the documentation under "Post-init processing"

> The `__init__()` method generated by `dataclass()` does not call base class `__init__()` methods. If the base class has an `__init__()` method that has to be called, it is common to call this method in a `__post_init__()` method:

In your case,

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Message:
    op: MessageType


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Hello(Message):
    op: MessageType = field(init=False)
    foo: str

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__init__(MessageType.HELLO)
```

Unfortunately, it appears necessary to redefine `op` to not be passed to  `Hello.__init__`.

Comment: How does this compare to `field(init=False, default=MessageType.HELLO)`?

Comment: `default` implies that you could provide a (different) value if you preferred, which doesn't make sense in this case. (The fact that it's not a parameter to `__init__` in the first place mitigates that concern somewhat.)